# What is the difference between service and server?

Tags: service

It seems that both service and server refer to some web based application. But is there any precise definition of the two terms?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A server offers one or more services. Server is also a more technical term, whereas service is more a term off the problem domain.

You also need to distinguish between:

- Server as hardware (see post from Dan D)
- Server as software (eg. Apache HTTP server)

You can find more elaborate definiton on Wikipedia:

- [Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_(systems_architecture))
- [Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing))

Answer (score 10):

This is regardless of client-server or P2P models.
A server provides services to one or more clients, and a server(hardware) is a computer. A server(hardware) can be anything from a home computer to a big server-rack with a lot of processor power.
From the view of a computer, a server(software) is just a set of services which is available to clients on the network.

Some well known services are web-server, mail-server. ftp-server. notice they are called xxx-server because such programs consist of a client and server part. The postfix is mainly to distinguish whether we are talking about the client or the server.

So at what moment do we call something a server? We do it when a computer shares some service/content on the network, which is accessible by clients. In other words, when we make a server as defined for software.

Regarding the P2P model: every one is both a client and a server, hence called servent. The above apply to the server part of a P2P network, just remember that it also can be a client.

Futher reading:

[Client-Server model](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/cs/csintro.php3)

[P2P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)

Answer (score 1):

a server is a piece of hardware or on a virtual machine

a service is a process that provides services normally over the network and runs on a server

but a server can also refer to a web server which is actual a service but it's sort of like one as it hosts services

i think those are reasonable working definitions

Comment: But Microsoft calls some of its server feature "server" e.g. SMTP Server and some "services" e.g. SNMP services.So SMTP server in this case is not a hardware nor virtual machine as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way to define both besides the definition of the server being a piece of hardware, a server in the software sense is a service that serves data.  In other words you interact with a server with a request and you should get a response back.  It "serves" data.

A service does not need interaction and is pretty much just a random process that keeps running doing the same thing, but a server is a service because it is basically a process that keep waiting for a request to come in so that it can return a response.

Answer (score 0):

*"A service is a component that performs operations in the background without a user interface."*
~ [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

### Services don't just run on servers

#### Shell services

Services can run from the shell. Unix refers to services as Daemons (pronounced "demons"), and Windows refers to them as services.

#### Client-side services

Services can run client-side. Mozilla (and other browsers) support [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which run in a background thread. [Client-side frameworks, like Angular, support services as well.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)